# How to create tournament bracket

Tags: graphics, combinatorics

I'd like to create a tournament bracket using Mathematica. I've looked around online, but haven't found any examples yet. Can someone show me how to do this? Specifically, I'd like to have a (somewhat) arbitrary number of participants in a double-elimination bracket.

**Edit** by belisarius

An example of a [double elimination bracket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-elimination_tournament) follows

[image]

Each team has to be beaten twice to be eliminated. There are a winners and a losers circuit, and when a team loses a match in the winner's side, it enters the losers circuit in an appropriate place, so not to be confronted with past competitors.

Comment: What have you tried? "Can someone show me how to do this?" isn't a very inviting question. We aren't here to do your job for you. I would suggest trying to use a combination of primitive graphics (`Line`, `Text`, etc.) to put something together. The `LevelScheme` package might be helpful as well.

Comment: Here's one example: http://blog.wolfram.com/2009/03/16/march-madness-in-mathematica/

Comment: @belisarius Team 5 only lost once. Why was it eliminated from the tournament?

Comment: @David Two options: The tournament council is a nest of corrupt rats, or I made a mistake

Comment: @David See the new bracket example, pls

Comment: @belisarius The nerve of that tournament council!

Comment: Sorry I didn't have something to start with. I was hoping someone had already done this and could point me to an example. The edit made by @belisarius is a good start.

Answer (score 7):

Here a basic idea for starters. I use a binary tree which is visualized with `TreeGraph`. A custom `EdgeShapeFunction` takes care of the right-angled edges. I leave further customizing of the labels and the rest of the tree as an exercise to the reader.

```
tree = Flatten@
   Table[{i \[UndirectedEdge] 2 i, i \[UndirectedEdge] 2 i + 1}, {i, 1, 2^4 - 1}];

start = RandomSample[CountryData["EuropeanUnion"], 16];

tournament= Reverse@Flatten@NestList[
     Flatten[(Function[{win}, RandomSample[win, 1]] /@ Partition[#, 2])] &, start, 5];

TreeGraph[
  tree, 
  VertexShape -> 
     (#1 -> 
       Graphics[Style[Text[#2], 14], PlotRangePadding -> 0.2, 
                ImageSize -> 1.5 {40, 15}
       ] & @@@ ({Range[31], tournament}\[Transpose])
     ), 
  VertexSize -> 1, EdgeStyle -> Blue, 
  EdgeShapeFunction -> ({Line[{#1[[1]], {#1[[2, 1]], #1[[1, 2]]}, #1[[2]]}]} &)
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I think he is not after a drawing, but after the `double elimination part` http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-elimination_tournament

Comment: This looks great! I am interested in drawing, but also double elimination. I don't have something to start with; I was hoping someone had already created something I could start with. I didn't know about the TreeGraph so this looks like something I could use, but definitely needs double elimination.